# A Program written by C that return 0xC0000005

Tags: c

**l'm a student of zju from china , this is my PTA quertion, the program will return 0xC0000005 when run it on clion.

Please help to solve the problem and tell me the reason.

Thx.**

it's my code:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int weights[10010];
int hats[10010], hats2[10010];
int weight2Pos[10010];
int rank2Weight[10010];
int hats2Rank[10010];
int cmp(const void* _a , const void* _b)
{
int* a = (int*)_a;
int* b = (int*)_b;
return *b - *a;
}
void sort_1(int n)
{
    qsort(hats2[0],n,sizeof(int),cmp);
}
void sort_2(int n)
{
    qsort(weights[0],n,sizeof(int),cmp);
}
int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        scanf("%d", &hats[i]);
        hats2[i] = hats[i];
    }
    sort_1(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) hats2Rank[hats2[i]] = i + 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        scanf("%d", &weights[i]);
        weight2Pos[weights[i]] = i + 1;
    }
    sort_2(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) rank2Weight[i + 1] = weights[i];

    for(int i = n - 1; i >= 0; --i){
        if(i == 0) printf("%d\n", weight2Pos[rank2Weight[hats2Rank[hats[i]]]]);
        else printf("%d ", weight2Pos[rank2Weight[hats2Rank[hats[i]]]]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**The question:**

PATers believe that wearing hats makes them look handsome, so wherever they go, everyone of them would wear a hat. One day they came to a restaurant, a waiter collected their hats and piled them up. But then when they were ready to leave, they had to face a stack of hats as shown by the above figure. So your job is to help them line up so that everyone can pick up his/her hat one by one in order without any trouble.

It is known that every hat has a unique size, which is related to the weight of its owner -- that is, the heavier one wears larger hat.

Input Specification:
Each input file contains one test case. For each case, the first line contains a positive number N (≤104) which is the number of PATers. The next line gives N distinct sizes of the hats, which are positive numbers no more than 105.The sizes correspond to the hats from bottom up on the stack. Finally in the last line, N distinct weights are given, correspond to the hat owners numbered from 1 to N. The weights are positive numbers no more than 106. All the numbers in a line are separated by spaces.
Output Specification:
For each test case, print in a line the indices of the hat owners in the order of picking up their hats. All the numbers must be separated by exactly 1 space, and there must be no extra space at the beginning or the end of the line.

Sample Input:
10
12 19 13 11 15 18 17 14 16 20
67 90 180 98 87 105 76 88 150 124
Sample Output:
3 4 8 6 10 2 1 5 9 7

Comment: Please read [ask].  Have you run the code in a debugger to see where the error is?  Learning to debug a program is just as important as learning the language.  If you don't know how to do that, there are many online tutorials to search for.

Comment: Why are you passing only one element of an array to `qsort`?

Comment: YC ZHANG, Save time.  Enable all compiler warnings.  Fast to find problems like `qsort(hats2[0],n,sizeof(int),cmp);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only problem is in your invocations of `qsort`. Change them to:

```
qsort(hats2,n,sizeof(int),cmp);
```

and

```
qsort(weights,n,sizeof(int),cmp);
```

Other than that, your program runs fine and produces the expected output.

Alternatively, you could use

```
qsort(&hats2[0],n,sizeof(int),cmp);
```

and

```
qsort(&weights[0],n,sizeof(int),cmp);
```

but the first is a bit simpler.